# Finding top 5 worst performing customers by salesperson

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view that returns data as follows:

```
|   salesman   |   customer   |  invoiced   |  budgeted   |  difference 
|--------------|--------------|-------------|-------------|--------------
| Joe          |   ACME Ltd   |     1000    |     2000    |    -1 000 
| Sam          |   Apple      |     1500    |     1100    |    +400 
| Joe          |   Apple      |     2000    |     2300    |    -300 
| Kim          |   ACME Ltd   |     1000    |     1500    |    -500
```

This is a snippet of of over 1500 rows that are returned. What I would like to do is return all rows by salesman showing that salespersons 5 worst customers sales. Each salesperson would therefore have 5 rows and each salesperson does sell to various customers who can be the same customer as another salesperson... right now I am looking at 5 worst customers by salesperson by value.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: What are you defining as "worst performing?"  The largest negative difference?

Comment: Try searching questions with the [`greatest-n-per-group` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group), this should point you towards your answer (which will almost certainly involve a windowed function (`RANK()`, `DENSE_RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()`).

Comment: Budgeted means it's the actual invoice and invoiced is the amount that is paid right??

Comment: Budgeted is the amount the salesperson thought they would achive at the beginning of the year/period.

Comment: Worst performing is as you say the largest negative difference

Answer (score 1):

Since one salesman can invoice the same company multiple times, you need to average the invoice amount across that group, then rank withing that partition and take the top five. If you are looking for the absolute worse sale per salesman then you would need to replace AVG with MIN.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        salesman,
        customer,
        AverageInvoiced,
        DescendingRank=DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY salesman ORDER BY AverageInvoiced DESC)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            salesman,
            customer,
            AverageInvoiced=AVG(invoiced) 
        FROM
            Table
        WHERE
        GROUP BY
            salesman,
            customer    
    )
)AS A
WHERE
    DescendingRank<=5
```

Comment: I think the partition should simply be by salesman, if you include customer you reduce it to one row per partition, so every row will have a dense_rank of less than or equal to 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this

TRy This

```
SELECT
*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            salesman,
            customer,
            AverageDiffrence,
            DescendingRank=DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY salesman ORDER BY AverageDiffrence DESC)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                salesman,
                customer,
                AverageDiffrence=AVG(difference) 
            FROM
                ireports_salesman_variance
            WHERE
            GROUP BY
                salesman,
                customer    
        )
    )AS A
    WHERE
        DescendingRank<=5
```

Comment: this only gets the top 5 for a particular salesperson - I would like top 5 for each and every salesperson

Comment: Now try this i have used the answer Ross Bush but instead of taking AVG of invoice if have AVG of difference.

Comment: I have tried this and get an error in SQL... my column names are  salesman, name and diff - and table name is ireports_salesman_variance could you transpose just iun case I am getting confused?

Comment: Now Check if it still gives any error please send the error

Comment: In 2 of these solutions you have used `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` which is not guaranteed to return the same results every time, let alone the results in the order you actually want. In the final solution you have simply coped the other answer (fairly obvious since the formatting is identical, it includes the same empty `WHERE` clause, most of the aliases are the same and you made the same mistake in missing out the alias from the innermost subquery)

Comment: I know that's why I mentioned this in my third answer but as you can see that my answer is based on the difference column not on invoiced column which I found usefull and the logic which I made was also the same as the answer given by Ross bush I used his query. Is this wrong ?? GarethD

Comment: The first parts were wrong, and the reason for my original down vote (which I have now removed since the incorrect parts have been removed). The 3rd bit was not wrong, and actually using the `difference` column is probably the correct column to use based on the logic described in the comments on the question. This difference was not abundantly clear though, which is why answers are much, much more useful when the come with a bit of explanation, rather than simply *"Try this"*.

Comment: Okay thank you GarethD I'll be taken care of next time and thank you for your precious time and suggestion, I didn't know that TOP without an ORDER BY which is not guaranteed to return the same results every time.